# PHP Read file and check if a certain string exists

Tags: php

So far this is what I have, but it doesn't seem to be working...

```
    <?
    $file = fopen('wiu.dat','r')
    while (wui = fgets($file)){
    if ($wui = 'True') {
      header("Location: index.html");
      die()
    } else {
      echo"<h2>Down for maintenance.</h2>"
    ;}}
    fclose($fh);
    ?>
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the content of the wiu.dat file? Also edit the `if ($wui == 'True')` statement.

Comment: Pretty sure you want to fclose before you die(), I could be wrong though.

Comment: missing a `$` in `while (wui` for one thing. If that's your actual code, error reporting's saying "undefined constant wui...".

Comment: @C1sc0
it will either be true or false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the obvious problems. I added a semicolon after your first line and after `die()`, changed `wui` to `$wui` in your `while` condition, changed `$wui = 'True'` to `$wui == 'True'`, changed `fclose($fh);` to `fclose($file);` and cleaned up your indentation just so it looks nicer. From there, I guess the success of the code depends on what you've got inside `wiu.dat`.

```
<?php
  $file = fopen('wiu.dat','r');
  while ($wui = fgets($file)) {
    if ($wui == 'True') {
      header("Location: index.html");
      die();
    } else {
      echo"<h2>Down for maintenance.</h2>";
    }
  }
  fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed all that, OP do you have error reporting turned off? These are all things a single test run should tell you!

Comment: @Glubus I'm new to web developement I didnt even think to open the console

Comment: In what environment are you coding then? You don't really use a console when you're programming php. Whenever you load the page it'll parse the error as html, unless you have your error reporting turned off, which you should not have.